# Form Postback Issue when changed form action at run time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am facing an issue when changing form action using jQuery as -

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "usersform" }))
...
<button type="button" onclick="SubmitUsersToLock()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
</button>
```

.js

```
function SubmitUsersToLock() 
{
    $('#usersform').attr('action', '/Users/LockUsers');
    alert($('#usersform').attr('action'));
    $('#usersform').submit();
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LockUsers(FormCollection usersForms)
{
    //.... Logic to lock user goes here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The alert in .js is showing correct value which is "/Users/LockUsers"
However control is not coming to Controller action - `LockUsers()`

Can anyone please guide what I am missing here?

Comment: Just tested the code you have show here and it works fine for me (the `LockUsers()` method is hit)

Comment: which browser did you use? I tried it on all three browsers IE, FF, Chrome.

Comment: Chrome - works fine. There must be some other issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply anyways. My form is just too big to post here. I will try to find the issue.

Comment: I assume you have included jquery. Are there any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

this code is valid:

```
 $('#usersform').attr('action', '/Users/LockUsers');
```

your problem is outside the code in this question.  you have some other error somewhere, or it is in fact working and you are not properly setting breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

I had to change below to make it work -

```
$('#usersform').submit();
```

to

```
document.forms.usersform.submit();
```